# ionic app rejected from app store

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to upload my first app to the appstore. It's built with ionic. Repo is here: https://github.com/irthos/rogo-app and is live here: https://irthos.github.io/rogo-app/

The email from apple said they tried it on a iPhone 4s:

> May 17, 2015 at 4:06 PM From Apple
>
> ```
> 2.1 - Apps that crash will be rejected
> ```
>
> 2.1 Details
>
> We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch on the
>   following device(s):
>
> - iPhone 5S running iOS 8.3
>
> We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.

Finally, here's the ips log from Apple: http://a1837.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple7/v4/30/c5/04/30c50456-c2c0-1148-8d60-f36fbb11ae26/temp..jwnucdaf.ips?downloadKey3=1432258092_57a71add8c408ca7ec7a907881e7a613

Thanks for any insight to this. I'll also post an issue on ionic's repo in case it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the crucial line is:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
```

Typically I would see this on a ViewController in a Storyboard where I changed the names of one of my IBOutlets in code but did not go and re-map the ViewController outlets on the storyboard.

Since I don't know what "ionic" is, I have no idea whether you are even using storyboards (or XIB's) or what tools you use but I would look at something UI related.

Just a guess though.